# (Pandas/Dataframe) pandas.json_normalize on nested JSON data without uniform record_path

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I'm attempting to convert a large JSON file to a CSV, but the field that I need to be able to sort data on in the Spreadsheet is all in one cell whenever I convert it to CSV/Normalize the JSON. The main thing I need is the `hits` list of dictionaries not all be in the same cell when I convert it to a csv.
(Structure is: a Dictionary of Dictionaries which contains a List of Dictionaries)

Here's an example of what the JSON would look like: https://pastebin.com/VA5mfhfB

Here's how I've tried doing it (and what gives somewhat of an output):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(boss_dictionary)
df.to_csv(r'data.csv', index=None)
```

I've tried putting a `record_path` parameter, but because there isn't a "uniform" boss_id (the slew of numbers beforehand), I can't figure out how to normalize the `hits` list of dictionaries.

Another thing that I've tried:

```
df = pd.read_json('data.json')
df.to_csv(r'data.csv', index=None)
```

Which does something *similar* to what I need, but not what I actually need. The hit list is just in one cell instead of being normalized out.

*What I've tried to fix it:*

I've tried to normalize it with the dictionary itself, and read it from JSON.
I've read the documentation on `json_normalize`, but no parameters of `meta` or `record_path` netted me any result that didn't raise an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using json_normalize with in a list comp based off keys.
Finally merge and explode.

```
from ast import literal_eval

import pandas as pd


data = literal_eval(open("/path/to/file/data.txt").read())

df_meta = (
    pd
    .concat([pd.json_normalize(data=data[x]) for x in data], keys=data.keys())
    .droplevel(level=1)
    .reset_index(names="id")
)

df_records = (
    pd
    .concat([pd.json_normalize(data=data[x], record_path=["hits"]) for x in data], keys=data.keys())
    .droplevel(level=1)
    .reset_index(names="id")
)

df_final = pd.merge(left=df_meta, right=df_records).drop(columns="hits")
df_final = df_final.explode("hp_list").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: How does this call from the data.json file or boss_dictionary? I'm not really sure how to tie in your answer to the dataframe setup I previously had.

ie. What would I need to edit about what I currently have to make it fit into your wonderful answer haha

Comment: "data" variable in my answer is the json from paste bin or boss_dictionary

Comment: Thanks for responding! I'm currently getting an error at .concat([pd.json_normalize(data=data[x]) for x in data], keys=data.keys()) --- NotImplementedError. I'm definitely under the assumption that this is due to my implementation and not yours, but I'll leave a link to a pastebin of all of my current code and you might be able to spot something I cant. I'm using pandas as a newbie who has just tried learning it through the docs and this is my first real time trying to use it in a project. https://pastebin.com/T3TU5Qgf

Do note that the first paste (OP) was the json data.

Comment: I just copied the pastebin of the json to a file called data.txt (replaced true with True and false with False) and read the file with: from ast import literal_eval. data = literal_eval(open("/path/to/file/data.txt").read())

Comment: ahh yeah i got it working! the only disparity is that its writing each hit in conjunction with each hp in hp list. Im assuming thats what the df_final.explore("hp_list") is supposed to prevent, but this is what the csv looks like for a single hit: https://pastebin.com/CkejHEB6. How would you modify it to idealy just remove the hp_list all-together from the dataframe? Thanks for the continued help Jason!

Comment: df_final = pd.merge(left=df_meta, right=df_records).drop(columns=["hits", "hp_list"])
# df_final = df_final.explode("hp_list").reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_final)